# Google Apps Script revision history only goes back a few days

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Google Apps script I've been working on all week.  I have 6 saved versions going back as far as 9/18.  I can go to "Manage Versions" and see all of them but I can't restore any of them.

When I got to "See Revision History" it only goes back to 9/21.

One thing to note, the majority of this project is in a .html file, not a .gs file.  Is there any hope to get at the code in the previous version?

Comment: I know how you can get all the script code out.  But not sure about the HTML.

Comment: If the code is a stand alone GAS project, may want to look into [node-google-apps-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-google-apps-script) to download/upload all of the code files (.gs/html) between your local machine and Google Drive. Then you could use Git or whatever version control you prefer. Google's version control is horrendous. May not help much with trying to get previous code; saves a lot of headaches going forward

Comment: This is an unanswered question @Alan Wells - you know how? Please tell us. I have created named versions but I find no documentation on restoring them. I see the little auto versions but they are file by file. It would be almost impossible to get all the files back to the same point in time. What are some tools outside GAS to manage a real project? Obviously, what we have now is not ready for complex projects.

Comment: See new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the code out of previous saved versions is with the Apps Script API.  The code editor doesn't have a way to load a previous saved version.
See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent

A version number can be designated.  If no version number is designated, then the head version is returned.

You'll need to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` if you want to use the Apps Script API from Apps Script.

```
function getAppsScriptContent() {
  var accessTkn,id,options,projectID,response,url;

  id = "";//Enter the project id here

  url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}/content";
  url = url.replace("{scriptId}", id);

  if (versionNumber) {
    url = url + '?versionNumber=' + versionNumber;
  }

  accessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  options = {};
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;//Make sure this is always set
  options.method = "GET";
  
  options.headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  accessTkn
    }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  if (!response || response .getResponseCode() !== 200) {   
      //Your error handling
  }

  fileContent = response.getContentText();
  
  try{
    fileContent = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    files = fileContent.files;
  }catch(e){
    
    //Error handling
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you run this? bound to something?

Comment: It can be run directly from the code editor.  If it were something that you needed to run on a recurring basis, they there are multiple other ways that you could trigger the code to run.